# Как отметить определенные radiobutton на странице?

Tags: checkbox

Как отметить определенные radiobutton на странице?
на странице надо заполнить автоматом пункты с определенными radio button
Не совсем понимаю как написать скрипт, чтобы в консоли запускать его нужной страницы и выставлять там на каждую кнопку "checked = true"

```
<input id="inp16" type="radio" name="inp-0-0" value="15">
<input id="inp33" type="radio" name="inp-1-0" value="15">
<input id="inp50" type="radio" name="inp-2-0" value="15">
<input id="inp67" type="radio" name="inp-3-0" value="15">
<input id="inp84" type="radio" name="inp-4-0" value="15">
<input id="inp101" type="radio" name="inp-5-0" value="15">
<input id="inp118" type="radio" name="inp-6-0" value="15">
<input id="inp135" type="radio" name="inp-7-0" value="15">
<input id="inp152" type="radio" name="inp-8-0" value="15">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
let inputs = ['inp50','inp101','inp135'];
[...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')].forEach(function(input){
  ~inputs.indexOf(input.id) && (input.checked = true);
})
```

```html
<input id="inp16" type="radio" name="inp-0-0" value="15">
<input id="inp33" type="radio" name="inp-1-0" value="15">
<input id="inp50" type="radio" name="inp-2-0" value="15">
<input id="inp67" type="radio" name="inp-3-0" value="15">
<input id="inp84" type="radio" name="inp-4-0" value="15">
<input id="inp101" type="radio" name="inp-5-0" value="15">
<input id="inp118" type="radio" name="inp-6-0" value="15">
<input id="inp135" type="radio" name="inp-7-0" value="15">
<input id="inp152" type="radio" name="inp-8-0" value="15">
```

Comment: Работает, мое почтение!

Comment: наберусь наглости и спрошу, можно ли и кнопку "отправить" сразу нажимать в этом скрипте?  <input id="submit_vote" type="submit" class="button" value="Отправить">

Comment: @ЛучСолнца не понял вопрос, уточните

Comment: на странице есть кнопка, которая отправляет результаты по заполненным radio buttons. Ее код выше. Теперь если в консоли я запускаю код, он выделяет нужные button'ы а дальше мне надо нажать кнопку "отправить". Думаю, можно ли ее вставить в тот же код с button'aми, чтобы она нажималась сразу после отметки нужных buttons

Comment: @ЛучСолнца я доберусь до компьютера и дополню ответ, ускакал от компа

Comment: @ЛучСолнца если навскидку то `document.querySelector("#submit_vote").click();`